# Is it OK ByteArrayOutputStream is not closed

Tags: java, bytearrayoutputstream

I am reading the following Java file: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintTextLocations.java?revision=1709154&view=co

In the linked code, the `ByteArrayOutputStream` is initialized but not CLOSED, is it OK? In my opinion, as `ByteArrayOutputStream` is `Closeable`, it should be closed eventually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html):

> Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect.

Comment: OMG, I just ignored reading the detail of the API :) Thanks anyway

Comment: @Rui the source for `close()` is also empty, but the docs let you know this won't change in future.

Comment: seems that since Java 7 the try-resource-statement can ignore this issue :)